# Iterating through XML w/ Element Tree and updating text from list

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So, I feel like this maybe a basic oversight on my behalf. But, I'm stuck on correctly updating XML text field with values from a list. I have a list with 4 elements in it `source = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. I can iterate through the XML and find the text values I need to update (simplified version below). What I'm failing to grasp is how to iterate through the `subfields` so that subfield.text is updated for the values in source.

I've tried -

```
for s in source:
    for su in root.iter('subfield'):
        if su.items()[-1][1] == 'Target':
            su.text = s # this makes all values d 
            print(su.text)

"""<field align="left" seq="1" type="text">aqwe
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>
   </field>
   <field align="left" seq="1" type="text">fghg
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>
   </field>
   <field align="left" seq="1" type="text">fdad
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>
   </field>
   <field align="left" seq="1" type="text">asdf
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>
   </field>
"""
```

Ideally it would be:

```
"""<field align="left" seq="1" type="text">aqwe
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>a
   </field>
   <field align="left" seq="1" type="text">fghg
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>b
   </field>
   <field align="left" seq="1" type="text">fdad
       <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>c
   </field>
   <field align="left" seq="1" type="text">asdf
        <subfield align="left" name="Target" type="text"/>d
   </field>
"""
```

Comment: Use only the inner `for su ...` and replace `su.text = s` with `su.text = source.pop(0)`

Comment: Thanks!!! - I had a feeling I was overthinking it, and `pop` - of course!